# .sh script if number > 100 send email with the number

Tags: perl, shell, sh

I am trying to write a script that looks at a .txt file and determins if the first number is greater or equal to 100. If it is then send an email, if it is not, do nothing.

Here is an example of what the .txt file would look like

vi output.txt

```
108
```

since that number is over 100 it should send an email of the number:

Example of email

```
You have 108 errors
```

This is what I got so far:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

filename = '/home/tted01/SPOOL/error.txt'

while read -r line
do
    id = $(cut -c-3 <<< "$line")
    echo $id >> /home/tted01/SPOOL/output.txt
done < "$filename"

mailx -s "ERRORS" ted.neal@gmail.com -- -f ted.neal@gmail.com < /home/tted01/SPOOL/output.txt
sleep 5

exit 0
```

I can't figure out the conditional statement and how to parse the variable.

Comment: if you only need to read the first of the file, then the `while` is overkill. just `read` the line. `$id` would contain your value, then you use `[`/`test` in bash to check the value in there.

Comment: Why is the perl tag with this question? Do you want solution in perl?

Comment: Yeah, I can do this using .sh or .pl any s.olution would work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple Perl script. Since we need to both send a message and a file, the example from the question is changed to *attach* the file. This seems suitable with a small text file, which content is discussed in the body anyway.  There are other ways to do this with `mailx`, see `man mailx` on your system.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = '/home/tted01/SPOOL/error.txt';
my $mark = 100;

# Slurp the whole file into a variable
my $cont = do {
    open my $fh, '<', $file  or die "Can't open $file -- $!";
    local $/; 
    <$fh>;
};

# Pull the first number
my ($num) = $cont =~ /^(\d+)/;

if ($num > $mark) 
{
    my $body = "You have $num errors.";
    my $cmd_email = "echo $body | " .
        "mailx -a $file -s \"ERROR\" ted.neal\@gmail.com";
    system($cmd_email) == 0  or die "Error sending email -- $!";
}
```

Since this is clearly a small enough file it is read in one go, into a variable. We extract the very first number that was in the file by a simple regex. (A "number" is understood as consecutive digits, up to anything other than a digit.)

The email command is executed via `system`, which in Perl uses `sh`. Perl's `system` returns a `0` if a command was executed without errors so we test against that. Note that this doesn't tell us how the command itself did, only whether it ran fine.  All this can be done in other ways, if needed -- one can use backticks (`qx`) to get back the output, with possible stream redirection in the command to get the error as well. Also, `bash` can be invoked explicitly if needed.

---

Here is another option for how to compose the message.  If the file is indeed so small, you can include its content in the message body.

Everything before and after this snippet stays as above.

```
my ($num) = $cont =~ /^(\d+)/;

chomp($cont);
my $body = "You have $num errors. Log file: $file. Content: $cont";

my $cmd_email = "echo $body | mailx -s \"ERROR\" ted.neal\@gmail.com";
```

Note that here we have to be careful with newlines, thus the `chomp` and no newlines in the message body. So this is pushing it a little.

If the log file may or may not be too large, you can check the number of lines and perhaps include the first 5 or 10 (and attach the file), or include the whole file as above (if small enough).  This is easy to process in Perl. You can refine this further a lot. Finally, if things grow and get sophisticated you can use Perl modules for email.

---

A very reasonable question came up -- what if the number is not the very first thing in the file?  What if it is the first thing on the second line, for example?

If the file is small, one can still read it into a variable like above and use a (more complicated) regex to find the pattern.  For example, if the number is the first thing on the second line

```
my ($num) = $cont =~ /.*\n(\d+)/;
```

The pattern matches the newline directly by `\n` and captures the first number after it.  Since there is no `/s` or such modifiers, a newline is not matched by `.` so the greedy `.*` does stop at the first newline, as needed.

However, this gets nastier very rapidly as more complicated requirements come. So better just process line by line.

```
# Instead of reading all content into $cont
open my $fh, '<', $file  or die "Can't open $file -- $!";

my $num;
while (my $line = <$fh>) 
{
    if ($. == 2) {                    # $. is number of lines read
        ($num) = $line =~ /^(\d+)/;
        last;                         # we are done, quit the loop
    }
}
# Process the same way as above
```

We use one of Perl's built-in *special variables*, `$.`, which holds the number of lines having been read from the (last accessed) filehandle.  See [Special Variables in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#SPECIAL-VARIABLES). Note that the line is read at `<>`, so inside the loop `$.` is `1` when we are processing the first line, etc. The regex is the same, and here is an explanation that is missing above.

The match `$line =~ m/.../` always returns a *list* of matches since it can match many times, so we 'catch' it in a list, using `()`.  Since there is clearly just one here it is enough to use one variable, thus `($num)`.  The `m/` may be omitted and you'll generally see it that way, `=~ /.../`.

This is a simple condition, that it's the second line.  But this way you can use far more sophisticated ones as well.

Comment: Thank you!!! Is there a way for the body to display like

'You have 108 errors' 

the 108 should come from the number in that .txt file

Comment: @connollyc4  You mean in the body of the email? That would be a matter of what `mailx` allows you to do.  I'll adjust the post for this, let me know.  You have options there, it depends on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: @connollyc4  I've updated the post considerably.  I changed how an email is sent, to what I think may be better (it's simpler), and offered yet another way to compose it.  Please let me know how this works for you.

Comment: Thank you zdim! I appreciate your help on this :)

Comment: quick question. If I wanted to look at the number on the second line instead of the first like, how would I be able to modify that part of the script?

I believe this line would need to be modified
my ($num) = $cont =~ /^(\d+)/;

Not sure how I can change that to look at the second line of the file and not the first

Comment: The only reason I asked about the second line is because my query that spools to a file looks like this:
``
`bash-3.2$ cat error.txt
'
210
bash-3.2$
`
For some reason I get a ' on the first line and the number is written on the second line every time.

Comment: @connollyc4  I don't quite understand the last comment, specially that command line.  But I've added more code, for more general conditions.  It's written to get the first number on the second line but should be very easy to adjust to something else. Let me know if there's more.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have bash script solution:-

```
#!/bin/bash
filename = '/home/tted01/SPOOL/error.txt'

while read -r line;
do
id =`echo $line`
    if [ $id -gt 100 ]; then
        mailx -s "You have $id errors" ted.neal@gmail.com  < /home/tted01/SPOOL/output.txt
    fi
sleep 5
done < filename
```

Comment: @connollyc4 - `mailx -s "You have $id errors" ted.neal@gmail.com,ted1.neal@gmail.com  < /home/tted01/SPOOL/output.txt` like this you can add more than 1 email addresses to send mail to. From output.txt file only body will be sent. you can mention your message in this file.